# General term for location or event

Tags: single-word-requests

I thought I would try my luck here. Is there a general term that encompasses locations and/or events?

For example, music festivals and towns?

Comment: Time and place? Can you explain more?

Comment: Time is irrelevant. I'm not sure how to explain any more to be honest. Perhaps this sentence can help: The set of <blah>'s in London includes all parks and concerts in London?

Comment: Oh, you mean tourist spots? Attractions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tourist attraction** (or tourist spot) — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tourist_attraction)

> A tourist attraction is a place of interest where tourists visit, typically for its inherent or exhibited natural or cultural value, historical significance, natural or built beauty, offering leisure, adventure and amusement.
>
> Natural beauty such as beaches, tropical island resorts with coral reefs, hiking and camping in national parks, mountains and forests, are examples of traditional tourist attractions to spend summer vacations. Other examples of cultural tourist attractions include historical places, monuments, ancient temples, zoos, aquaria, museums and art galleries, botanical gardens, buildings and structures (e.g., castles, libraries, former prisons, skyscrapers, bridges), theme parks and carnivals, living history museums, ethnic enclave communities, historic trains and cultural events. Factory tours, industrial heritage, creative art and crafts workshops are the object of cultural niches like industrial tourism and creative tourism. Many tourist attractions are also landmarks.

Or simply **attraction** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/attraction)

> something interesting or enjoyable that people want to visit, see, or do
>
> *"The waterfall continues to be the main attraction at the park."*
> *"The town's big attraction for movie lovers is the annual film festival."*

Comment: *Attraction* seems perfect for covering both, but *spots* surely only covers locations, not events?

Comment: @PLL If *spots* are used instead of *tourist spots*, I don't think it automatically includes any events. What word do you have in mind instead?