# Single word for "Tourist Attraction Places"

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a web directory... There are many categories like Hotel & Spa, Electric shops, etc.

Now I need to add "Tourist Attraction Places" as a category. Seems like that name is too long.

Is there any "single" or "two word" word can I use for "Tourist Attraction Places"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [General term for location or event](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/322429/50044).

Comment: "Tourist Attractions" would work fine.

Comment: Tourist Hotspots works ok.

Comment: [Related](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2160).

Answer (score 2):

My satnav (which is kind of a directory in this respect) calls things like that ***[POIs (Points of Interest)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_of_interest)***:

> A point of interest, or POI, is a specific point location that someone may find useful or interesting.

(Wikipedia)

Answer (score 0):

You may use ***[sights](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sight)***:

> places of interest, especially to visitors:
>
> - We spent a week in Rome looking at all the sights.

(Cambridge Dictionary)